# How to stop samsung device maintenance to put our app in sleep mode android?

Tags: android

I am developing one application in which there is Background Service, I want my application always run in background.

In Samsung device android 7.0 user can put the application in sleep mode, but I don't want user to do it because there is Background service is running.

Also it is good if I my app is listed in Unmonitered app list instead of direct listed in power saver mode.

When I install whatsapp it does that actually, it listed in Inmonitered app list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am suggesting for the only Samsung devices,

You can do it by using  Knox SDK which is used to create the application with custom configuration for Samsung device,

Here also some link which helps you.
[Response from Samsung moderator after question like same you](https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/want-add-my-app-unmonitor-list)
https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/applicationpolicyaddpackagetobatteryoptimizationwhitelist-does-not-work-normally

Maybe this all will help you.

Comment: @Jayesh use english